# Login username and password in Gmail with Windows 10 iot on raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have created app where I have added webview and redirected to Gmail login page.

```
GmailWebView.Navigate("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier")
```

Now I want to add user id and password and click on login but not able to do that. I am unable to add System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser so I can use it. Do we have any thing in win10 iot to complete this.

Comment: Are you trying to use google to authenticate as 3rd party or to literally log into gmail?

Comment: i am trying to login to gmail in webview where i can pass user id and password through code and select first email and open it.

Comment: is there any method we can use in win10 iot to enter data in text box on website and it redirect when we submit or login.

Answer (score 1):

First subscribe on **NavigationCompleted** in your webView like below

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" NavigationCompleted="webView_NavigationCompleted"></WebView>
```

After you navigate to your url and the navigate complete the NavigationCompleted raised.and you can controll your webView.

```
   await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] {
       "var usernameText=document.getElementById(\"UserName\");"+
       "var passwordText=document.getElementById(\"Password\");"+
       "var button=document.getElementById(\"SubmitButton\");"+
       "button.attachEvent('onclick', MyButtonClicked);"+
       "function MyButtonClicked(){" +
           " //click Function"+
       "}"
   });
```

Comment: getting below error   

`at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter``1.GetResult()
   at AllinOnePi.MainPage.<webView_NavigationCompleted>d__36.MoveNext()`

Comment: Dear @Farhan , You can interact with the content of the WebView by using the InvokeScriptAsync method to invoke or inject script into the WebView content, and the ScriptNotify event to get information back from the WebView content.
To invoke JavaScript inside the WebView content, use the InvokeScriptAsync method. The invoked script can return only string values.
for more info see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview)

Comment: i tried using below code but it is giving same as above exception
   defined uri in initialize Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=XMc7Wo2RE9KnvwSD2LeQDQ&gws_rd=ssl");
    `private async void webview_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {try{                
        string functionString = "document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = 'abc';"
        await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
        } catch (Exception ex)
        { LogTextbox.Text = ex.Message; }}`

Comment: which line exactly do you get error ? i can`t find out why and where you get error.

Comment: while executing `webview.InvokeScriptAsync` gives error

Comment: when i changed `"document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = 'abc'` code `.value` to `.InnerText` then it continues without error but does not set the values in text box.

Comment: @Farhan make sure your code first work properly in browser then use it in **InvokeScriptAsync** method